# Returning multiple indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, position

I have an array that is similar down below.

```
var my_array = ['Hello', 'How Are you?', 'Hello', 'Good morning!', 'Hello'];
```

my goal is to get all the position that has a value of 'Hello'

Desire result:

0, 2, 4

Whenever I tried my_array .indexOf("Hello"). It only returns 0 which is the first that is found.

Answer (score 2):

```
function indexesOf(str,arr){
    var res = [];
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i] == str)
            res.push(i);
    }
    return res;
}
var my_array = ['Hello', 'How Are you?', 'Hello', 'Good morning!', 'Hello'];
var indexes = indexesOf("Hello", my_array);
```

or you can use Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.indexesOf = function (str){
    var res = [];
    for(i=0;i<this.length;i++){
        if(this[i] == str)
            res.push(i);
    }
    return res;
}

var my_array = ['Hello', 'How Are you?', 'Hello', 'Good morning!', 'Hello'];
var indexes = my_array.indexesOf("Hello");
```

Comment: This is pretty much the recommended approach, but I don't think modifying `Array.prototype` is a good idea for such a simple task. Otherwise, I'd say this answers the question perfectly.

Comment: You changed the array. This won't work with the array he provided.

Comment: @IvyLynx, I agree, though it seems nicer for me to use `array.func()` :)

@Brad.Smith, thanks, fixed that

Comment: Actually, that's a bit my fault at well. For some reason I thought his original array had 'Hello' as a part of one of the array elements (ie 'Hello World') which is why I used a regex match. Looking back that's not the case.

Comment: @Brad.Smith, well your answer with regexp solves that case, so the topic starter will use the one he needs, + to you anyway

Answer (score 1):

I originally thought your question had elements with partial matches as well which it doesn't. In any case, if you wanted to include partial matches this would work for you:

```
var my_array = ['Hello', 'How Are you?', 'Hello World', 'Good morning!', 'Hello'];
function indexesOf(str,array) {
    var arr = [], re = new RegExp(str, 'g');
    array.forEach(function(val,idx) {
        if (val.match(re)) { arr.push(idx) }
    });
    return arr;
}
console.log(indexesOf('Hello',my_array));
```